# How to correctly use a boolean operator when analyzing a string in an if-statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, expression, boolean-operations

When I want to check if different part of a string is in a value, it doesn't work if I don't precise the value for each part of string (as in the if statement).

So I guess, the correct way is the one used in my elif statement.

Am I right ? Is there another way to check if some different words have been entered through a raw_input() ?

```
# we offer a choice
print "What do you want to do ?"
print "1. Listen to radio"
print "2. Turn on TV"

# we ask for an answer through raw_input()
choice = raw_input()

# we use an if-statement to print different strings for each choice provided
if "listen" or "radio" in choice:
    print "Let's listen some music !"
elif "turn" in choice or "TV" in choice:
    print "Let's watch a movie !"
else:
    print "I don't understand what you want to do"
    exit(0)
```

Thanks. I'm new to python (but I think it is pretty obvious)

Comment: Your `if` line should be `if "listen" in choice or "radio" in choice:`

Comment: You've been bitten by a particularly common Python misunderstanding. The combination of "or" not working the same as it does in English combined with the ability of any object to provide a "truthy" value gives surprising results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
if "listen" or "radio" in choice:
```

should be:

```
if "listen" in choice.lower() or "radio" in choice.lower():
```

Etc.